# Errors while trying to handle a catch block

Tags: java, debugging

So right now I am coding a program that takes in user input, which is recipes, and reads the recipes from a different file and then outputs the recipe to a new file called "ShoppingList.txt". I am trying to create the file but when I try to compile the program I am presented with this error.
 RecipeList.java:80: error: exception FileNotFoundException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
                catch(FileNotFoundException e) Can someone help me debug it. Thank you!

```
//Prasanth Dendukuri
// 2/5/18
// RecipeList.java


import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class RecipeList
{
    private Scanner terminal; // to read in input from kb
    private Scanner reader; // to read in from the text fi;e
    private String inFileName; // name of file to read from
    private String outFileName; // name of file to output to
    private String[] recipeList; // array that contains the recipes
    private String[] ingredients; // array that contains ingredients for each recipe
    private PrintWriter output; // print writer for writing to output file
    private String input; // to accept input and store in this variable
    private int numInput; // num of recipes entered
    private Scanner file; // scanner used for reading in from file

    public RecipeList()
    {
        terminal = new Scanner(System.in);
        inFileName = new String("Recipes.txt");
        outFileName =  new String("ShoppingList.txt");
        recipeList =  new String[20];
        ingredients = new String[20];
        input = new String(" ");
        output = null;
        numInput = 0;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        RecipeList rl = new RecipeList();
        rl.run();
    }

    // calls all methods and prints blank lines
    public void run() 
    {
        System.out.print("\n\n\n");
        getInput();
        openRecipes();
        makeFile();
        readFile();
        output.close();
    }

    // gets input of recipes until 'quit' is entered
    public void getInput()
    {
        while(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))
        {
            System.out.print("Type in a recipe.Type quit to end the program--> ");
            input = terminal.nextLine();

            if(!input.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))
            {
                recipeList[numInput] = input;
                numInput++;
            }
        }

    }

    //opens RecipeList and handles exceptions 
    public void openRecipes()
    {
        File inFile = new File(inFileName);
        try
        {
            file = new Scanner(inFileName);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.err.println("ERROR. Could not read/find file.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    // makes ShoppingList.txt and handles exceptions 
    public void makeFile()
    {
        File outFile = new File(outFileName);

        try
        {
            output = new PrintWriter(outFile);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("ERROR. Could not read/find file.");
            System.exit(2);
        }
    }

    public void readFile()
    {
        String directions = new String("");

        while(file.hasNext())
        {
            directions = file.next();
        }

        output.print(directions);

    }

}

            ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code, see my comments

```
    File inFile = new File(inFileName);
    try
    {
        file = new Scanner(inFileName);  
        // you are trying to use the Scanner using a `String`
        // this does not throw an Exception, hence the compile error
        // I think you want to use
        // public Scanner(File source) which throws a FileNotFoundException
        // so change to use instead
        file = new Scanner(inFile);  
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.err.println("ERROR. Could not read/find file.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: Oh.. no wonder... I was trying to make the scanner to read in a string instead of a file. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with openRecipes() method. You are trying to handle FileNotFoundException whereas it is not thrown by scanner class. Use the file object what you have created in scanner class and it will start working. Copy paste following code.

```
public void openRecipes()
    {
        File inFile = new File(inFileName);
        try
        {
            file = new Scanner(inFile);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.err.println("ERROR. Could not read/find file.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer add anything to my existing answer?